# How to set style of header and footer with horizontal lines in report document type?

Tags: header-footer, rules

How can I set the header and footer for pages as in the picture below:

1. On the top - title of the document and horizontal line below it.
2. On the bottom - author's name and title of subsection on the left side and page numbering on the right, with horizontal line above.

[image: page layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using the `scrpage2` package from the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html) bundle.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline,footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
\automark{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{(Document title)}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Optional argument controls chapter-starting pages
\ifoot[(Author) -- \headmark]{(Author) -- \headmark}

\renewcommand*{\footfont}{\normalfont\slshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Used the `\automark` command in order to display section headings.

Comment: I needed to add `\usepackage[english]{babel}` before this would compile...

Comment: @Seamus: No, you only need to delete all auxiliary files before compiling.

Comment: you forgot about `plainheadsepline` but it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use [the memoir documentclass](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/), then setting `\makeheadrule` and `makefootrule` appropriately should do it.

```
\documentclass[openany,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % This package generates blind text. It's not part of the example per se...

\title{This is the title}
\author{A. Author}

\makeheadrule{plain}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{plain}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{0ex}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\thetitle}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{\theauthor}{}{\thepage} 

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Section another}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you'd rather the rules didn't appear on the title page and on the first page of the chapter, replace `plain` by something else throughout.

Comment: `\makefootrule` doesn't seem to work. Also, memoir has a `\normalrulethickness` macro which pretty much does the first line there...

Comment: `\makefootrule` takes a fourth argument: skip, which should be a vertical distance

Comment: I have a working memoir version that almost works, I can edit it into your answer if you'd like? `\sectiontitle` doesn't work, though...

Comment: @Seamus: Sure.  I'll CW this.

Comment: I've added a MWE. The only thing that doesn't work is the section title in the footer...

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is probably the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. Here's a MWE for the article class that almost works... (The titling package defines `\theauthor` and `\thetitle` commands that *should* print the contents of `\author{}` and `\title{}` respectively. But `\thetitle` seems to have broken...

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{This is the title}
\title{\mytitle}
\author{A. Author}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
\headrule
\sethead{\mytitle}{}{}
\setfoot{\theauthor --- \sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
\footrule
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\newpage

\section{Section another}

\end{document}
```

Of course, since the title of the document doesn't change you can just set it yourself. Or use a trick like defining `\newcommand{\mytitle}{This is the Title}` and then putting `\title{\mytitle}` and then putting `\mytitle` in the relevant place in this example.

This all works fine with report class, and since the OP asked for report class, that's what I went with. But I'd actually recommend the KOMA or memoir solutions, since they're better in general...

As it stands at the moment, this solution does everything automatically except the document title (which can be done with the `\mytitle` trick. There's a memoir solution that works with everything except the subsection title. Lockstep's KOMA solution can automatically do title and author if you add the `titling` package...

Comment: OK, `titlesec` seems to be breaking `titling`. Or rather, it's breaking `\thetitle`

Comment: @Seamus: I modified my example so that section headings will be displayed.

Comment: @Seamus: Your minimal example uses the article class. With report, you also have to redefine the `plain` pagestyle - that's why I prefer the `scrpage2` package, which handles this in an elegant way.

Comment: @lockstep Or you can just renew the plain page style. I personally prefer not having a header above the chapter heading. I guess if you wanted the footer, but not the header it would involve some shenanigans...

Comment: @Seamus: My minimal example does exactly that - footer, but no header.

Comment: Yes I saw that. It is neater.